# Photoshop - Paste in Place on Different Artboard

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm searching for an option in Photoshop ,how I can paste in place object on different Artboard, as it works in Illustrator , thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Use copy method with <kbd>alt</kbd>**

Basically, there are many of ways to duplicate layers in Photoshop, and I use various methods in different scenarios, but in your case instead of using normal copy paste, try the following:

- Select the layers/ groups you want to copy
- Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and drag your layers to another
  artboard! Make sure you drag only after pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>
  otherwise it won't work!

In case you can't do it, here is a demo. Cheers :D

[image]